# count number of observations between two overlapping dates r

Tags: r, date, dataframe

Let's say we have a data frame defined as follows:

```
mydata <- data.frame(id = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                     start_date = as.Date(c('2012-08-05',
                                            '2013-05-04',
                                            '2012-02-01',
                                            '2015-03-02')),
                     end_date = as.Date(c('2014-01-12',
                                          '2015-06-05',
                                          '2016-05-06',
                                          '2017-09-12')))
```

Where `start_date` talks about the day an employee joined and `end_date` talks about the day he left and `id` is the unique employee id.

For each month from 5 August 2012 (the earliest `start_date`) to 12 September 2017 (the latest `end_date`) **I would like the employee count month wise.** The final output should be in a format similar to the one below: (doesn't matter if its in wide format or long format)
[image: Final Output Table]

In the table above the columns denote the months (1 to 12), the rows the year and the cells in the table the number of employees in that month.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution with `mapply` in base R.

```
# Function to get date of first day of a month (by @digEmAll)
toFirstDayOfMonth <- function(dates) dates - as.POSIXlt(dates)$mday + 1

# Generate all dates
dates <- Reduce(c, with(mydata, mapply(seq, toFirstDayOfMonth(start_date), end_date,
                                       by = "month")))

# Count occurrences of year/month combinations
table(format(dates, "%Y"), format(dates, "%m"))
```

The result:

```
       01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
  2012  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2
  2013  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
  2014  3  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2015  2  2  3  3  3  3  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2016  2  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  2017  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: @PoGibas Yes, `seq.Date` is a handy function.

Comment: Please note that : `seq(from=as.Date("2014-01-12"),to=as.Date("2014-02-01"),by="month")` returns only "2014-01-12", so I think you should normalize the date to the first day of the month before passing to mapply... e.g. using `toFirstDayOfMonth <- function(dates) dates - as.POSIXlt(dates)$mday + 1`

Comment: @digEmAll Good find! Thanks for pointing out. I added your function to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A solution from `tidyverse` and `lubridate`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

mydata2 <- mydata %>%
  mutate(Dates = map2(start_date, end_date, ~seq(.x, .y, by = "day"))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(Year = year(Dates), Month = month(Dates)) %>%
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(Employee = n_distinct(id)) %>%
  spread(Month, Employee, fill = 0)
mydata2
# A tibble: 6 x 13
# Groups:   Year [6]
   Year   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`
* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2012     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2
2  2013     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
3  2014     3     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
4  2015     2     2     3     3     3     3     2     2     2     2     2     2
5  2016     2     2     2     2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
6  2017     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: This is a great answer as well but Sven Hohenstein's answer was succinct.

Comment: @JashShah I agree. If I were you I will also accept Sven Hohenstein's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
table(unlist(lapply(1:nrow(mydata), function(x) {
    format(seq(from=mydata[x,2],to=mydata[x,3],by="month"),"%Y-%m")
    })))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also a `data.table` package or combo of `data.table` and `dplyr`.

I will show the `dplyr` and `data.table` version (The only reason I use dplyr is the `%>%` operator. You could also do the whole thing in one line without using `%>%`).

```
# load data.table
library(data.table)
# load dplyr
library(dplyr)

#for each employee id, list first days of months during which employee was working, then transform from long to wide format using dcast function
dt <- setDT(mydata)[, list(date = seq(as.Date(format(min(start_date), "%Y-%m-01")),
 as.Date(format(max(end_date), "%Y-%m-01")),
 by = "month")), by = id] %>% dcast(year(date) ~ month(date))
```

What exactly the code above does?

the `by = id` tells you that the operation (the calculation of dates in this case) in `data.table` will be performed for each employee id.

`format(max(end_date), "%Y-%m-01")` gives you the start of the last month during which each of the employee worked.

`format(min(start_date), "%Y-%m-01)"` start of the month in which the employee started working.

`seq(..., ...., by = "month")` gives you first day of all the months in which each of the employees worked.

`%>%` is the piping operator, it means "then". It is the same as using the result of setDT(mydata)[..., ..., ...] as the first parameter of `dcast` function.

`dcast` function transforms the `long` format (in this case, the result of `setDT[...]`) to `wide` format.

End that is the end :)